# Link anchor tag in wordpress site to wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to move a website of static pages over to wordpress. In my main navigation menu on the main page, how do I edit the navigation menu such that when I clicked on the links the user is directed to the other static html pages as well? I knew pages in wordpress are similar in function, so how do I actually put the html code for them in these pages in wordpress? Been trying out but have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You do it through the menu editor...

You can add a link to wherever you wish.

If you wish to do so Pragmatically here is an explanation: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/programmatically-add-a-navigation-menu-and-menu-items